# UDP comunication at the and of a TCP request

Tags: https, tcp, udp

I'm learning about network protocols, in particular TCP and UDP. I've written a c++ client that get the HTTPS response of this page `216.58.198.35` (Google), then I've used Wireshark to analyze the communication.

The first part was, as supposed, the TCP communication.

The second part, for me, is a little bit more difficult to understand. It's an UDP communication, with the following screenshot from Wireshark:
 [image: Wireshark screenshot with UDP communication]

For the first communication: *source port* is 64522, *destination port* 443. What is it? I don't understand its meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is the [QUIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QUIC) protocol which is in the process of moving to be the underlying transport for the the HTTP/3 standard.